# React Native Router Flux with Drawer and Swiper

Tags: react-native, redux, swiper.js, react-native-router-flux

I couldn't figure out a way to scroll swiper when a button pressed inside a drawer.

To be exact: One component has a full screen swiper. When user clicks on hamburger button, drawer shows up with an array of *swiper datasource items*. I would like to navigate to clicked *datasource item* inside my component. Swiper already has a scrollBy function for this. I just need to know how can I possibly trigger my swiper to scroll x indexes.

I'm using Redux model in my application. I've tried to pass the reference of swiper via reducers but it just seemed wrong.

Comment: Did you find some solution for this issue yet?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, back then I've used Events and emitters. It's not a react way solution but it worked